# why fadeOut/fadeIn stack up when I click the red square to fadeout?

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a simple content slider. When someone click the red square so many times the slide will stack up.
I used setTimeout to prevent many clicks when its working, but it again stacked up. unbind/bind didn't work either. In [this jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/dJQZM/4/) I have put a sample. What should I do to prevent showing the next slide so many times when someone click the red square?

This is a code I've used with unbind that does not work:

```
$(function(){
    $(".circle").click(function(e){
        $(".circle").unbind('click');
        var ref = $(this);
        var id= parseInt(ref.attr('id'));
        $(".circle").attr('src','inactive-circle.gif');
        ref.attr('src','active-circle.gif');
        $(".boxicon").fadeOut(50,function(){
            $("#slide"+id).fadeIn(450);
            $(".circle").bind('click');
        });



    });
})
```

**The final result with a little changes:**

```
$(".circle").click(function() {
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10);
    $(".circle").attr('src', 'inactive-circle.gif');
    $(this).attr('src', 'active-circle.gif');
        $(".boxicon").hide();
    $("#slide" + id).stop(true, false).fadeIn(250);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few mistakes I can see,

When you're doing a `var ref = $(this)`, you then don't need to do a `$(ref)`,

So you're lines,

```
$(ref).attr('id') 

$(ref).attr('src','active-circle.gif');
```

Will be,

```
ref.attr('id') 

ref.attr('src','active-circle.gif');
```

That might be causing some problems, also,

**What are you trying to achieve?**

Just had a look at your markup in the fiddle, by that, your jQuery looks a bit messed up for a content slider.

**UPDATE**

```
$(function() {
    $(".circle").click(function() {
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10);

        /*the .each() here is optional, you can always do this,
        $(".circle").attr('src', 'inactive-circle.gif');
        */
        $(".circle").each(function() {
            $(this).attr('src', 'inactive-circle.gif');
        });


        $(this).attr('src', 'active-circle.gif');

        /*the .each() here is optional, you can always do this,
        $(".boxicon").fadeOut(50);
        */    
        $(".boxicon").each(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(50);
        });

        $("#slide" + id).stop(true, true).fadeIn(450);

    });
})​;
```

made appropriate changes (based on your markup), if you have any doubts, feel free to ask.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dJQZM/8/) (Have removed unused markup).

Comment: ref didn't solve the problem,but thanks for the tip. `Goal:` when a person clicks red square, then slide number 1 or 2 or 3 should fade in.

Comment: @phpGeek Updated my answer, please have a look :)

Comment: There was a little jump on the pictures that I didn't post. By changing `stop(true, true)` to stop(false, true) and `fadeOut` to `hide` everything works like a charm ;) thnk

Comment: Yes that, plus, `#slide` is a child of `.boxicon`, so a `.fadeOut()` on `.boxicon` fades-out `#slide` as well, also, you called `.fadeOut() #slide` in a callback, which wouldn't work. *Sorry, pretty bad with explanation*